# Создать игру виртуальный питомец на javascript

Tags: javascript

У меня есть jpg картинка. Как мне ее можно оживить через javascript по логике игры виртуального питомца? Подскажите материал, книги, ю-туб каналы, похожие примеры. 
С благодарностью.

Answer (score -1):

Есть хорошая книга по JS, называется "Графика на JavaScript". Там подробно рассказывается про графику и средства, включенные в HTML 5. Советую!

PDF: [скачать](https://psv4.userapi.com/c423228/u10903696/docs/40daf94c6340/Grafika_na_JavaScript_Rafaello_Chekko.pdf?extra=3LqxFJv6FhoA6sd4auG3QHetML-kWJvzLzblCP0-peSg2L2_-YQjqmoiLjjHd4l2BUJcViRjaM1jVjE9O3IaOaVlw0Dxnx3yVlf9F4gxj0kVNZx5fGmroXSm4nNoJuoI4jtT6wtgQQAJEg&dl=1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P. S. Для изучения книги потребуются начальные сведения о языке JavaScript, умение составить хотя бы элементарный алгоритм.